# Is there any software to autoformat the code written in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, code-formatting

Various software is used to auto-format the source code, written in different programming languages.

I mean exactly auto-formatting (not coloring) of the source code - add spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.

Is there any alternative way to do the same, but for the Makefiles?

I've tried to do it in "bash" with "grep", "sed", "awk" and I'm almost done.

P.S. As an example, please compare bad formatted Makefile.ugly:

```
CONFIG_ZERO=y
CONFIG_ONE=y
CONFIG_TWO=y

ifeq ($(CONFIG_ZERO),y)
list_of_targets += t1 t2 t4
ifeq ($(CONFIG_TWO),y)
list_of_targets += t5 t6 t7
endif
ifeq ($(CONFIG_ONE),y)
list_of_targets += t8 t9
endif
endif

.PHONY: all
all:
                $(info Using following targets: $(list_of_targets))
```

with its well-formatted version (Makefile.formatted):

```
CONFIG_ZERO=y
CONFIG_ONE=y
CONFIG_TWO=y

ifeq ($(CONFIG_ZERO),y)
  list_of_targets += t1 t2 t4

  ifeq ($(CONFIG_TWO),y)
    list_of_targets += t5 t6 t7
  endif

  ifeq ($(CONFIG_ONE),y)
    list_of_targets += t8 t9
  endif
endif

.PHONY: all
all:
    $(info Using following targets: $(list_of_targets))
```

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal layout of makefiles is relatively unchangeable: the leading tabulator for the recipe code (the shell code in a rule) is a syntactic element like in Python an can't be changed for the better (you can add more tabs, but the effect will likely be worse than nicer looking). Other code like variable definitions is only *prependable* by space characters, all spaces and tabs inside the body of such definitions and sometimes even the invisible spaces at the end serve a functional purpose and changing them has the chance to destroy their intended effect.

That leaves you with options for the vertical layout. Taking into consideration the two phases of execution of a makefile, you have two degrees of freedom: 1) variable definitions which don't have mutual dependecies and 2) the order of rules (with the exception of the first one which will serve as default target for a plain `make` call w/o arguments) are arbitary. This means you can move rules further to the back of the makefile *iff* the variables they use are not changing their contents in the course of the evaluation of the makefile - which in itself is not trivial to ascertain. A beautifier would have to construct the same internal data structures like `make` to decide if a source transformation is correct or not - and all that hassle for just a modest reordering of the rules.

TL;DR: `make` syntax is difficult to transform (under equivalence) and the resulting aesthetic will be hard to defend even among the same programming team, therefore it is seldomly done.

Comment: Thank you for extended comment. You're right. It is difficult to make such formatting software but it is possible (at list for some parts of Makefile, which are not rules, for example, for nested conditional definition of variables, functions, etc.). So, there is the same question. Is there any software to do this?

Comment: @lollol I once tried to do that but I couldn't even defend the result before myself. As `make` is lacking any larger structuring the result is about as messy as the original :D. I just live with it now and try to isolate the intensively maintained parts of a makefile by other means. Maybe you want to try [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which tries to bring a more structured approach to makefiles by supporting tables and  modest database functions like `select`

Comment: Thank you for advice. I've also tried to to it by myself. I've almost done it using grep/awk/sed. The problem is in fact, that I need to support Makefile, which counts more than 1500 lines with multiple level of nesting. That is why, I will not give up :)

Comment: "gmtt" looks nice. Will keep it in my mind.